# Firebase Cloud Messaging Issue

Tags: android, python, django

Currently doing a project which requires me to communicate and send notifications to my android device(s), from my server (django, running sqlite3 which is built in).

In order to make my life easier, i'll be utilising on Google's Firebase Cloud Messaging to bridge the gap and send the notifications to the android devices easily.

On Django(my server side), i'm using [django-fcm](https://django-fcm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library to do a http requests to the FCM server whenever i need to send a notification to my devices, which i believe have been set up properly.

The problem i'm facing currently would be that even though i have done a successful post from Django side to FCM server, the notification does not show on the FCM Console, and i have tried my best to do the necessary research to find a solution but to no avail.

By using the methods provided by this library, i've tried sending a message and this is the response given:

```
Kzhan00b-3:eldersense_website Kzhan00b$ python3 manage.py fcm_messenger --devices
Devices list:
(#7) Zhong Han


Kzhan00b-3:eldersense_website Kzhan00b$ python3 manage.py fcm_messenger --device_id=7 --msg='hello'
Using default settings.FCM_MAX_RECIPIENTS value 1. Change it via settings [OK] device #7 (Zhong Han):      
(['cbUqW...IimVXB'], 
{'results': [{'message_id': '0:1484576499555513%775b332838eb0007'}], 'multicast_id': 6536553600879447077, 'success': 1, 'failure': 0, 'canonical_ids': 0})
```

From the documentations which i've read, since there are no errors stated within the body, this post should be a successful request.

However, when i check on my console/emulated android device for any notification which was sent through this, nothing is shown, especially on the console side.

So in order to do a more robust investigation, i've tried doing a manual HTTP Post using the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library on python, referencing on the FCM documentation as follows:

```
r = requests.post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', 

data= json.dumps({'to':'cbUqWQ...rzSUIimVXB'}),
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json','
Authorization':'key=AAAA...nrgB8Y'})

>>> r.text
'{"multicast_id":7759794145591317544,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1484575515499197%775b3328f9fd7ecd"}]}'
>>> r.status_code
200
```

Which pretty much gives me the same response as using the django-fcm library as above, however, again no notification being received both on android or FCM server.

So i would like to seek for any advice if there's any thing which i'm doing incorrectly, causing a successful HTTP requests being done, and acknowledge by the FCM server, yet not showing on the FCM console.

Do let me know if you need me to show you codes from either my Django Server or Android side!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using django-fcm for the moment and it works fine. I don't see any notifications sent from the server in "Notifications" section of Firebase Console. It seems, this section is for manual sending of notifications. If I understand correctly, it stores history only about the messages, that were sent manually through it. As a minimum, I don't see the messages sent through django-fcm here. I think, your log messages are ok. Could you show the client code? In addition, it is better to add FCM_MAX_RECIPIENTS=1 to your Django's settings.py. (but it doesn't matter in the context of the problem, I think)